# How to capture the photo from camera on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

Based on [this article,](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) I'm trying do capture the photo from camera on Android Emulator. I followed the instructions as per they said. But I didn't get the positive result.

I'm getting the `Player` is `null`, while I'm running the `WebcamBroadcaster.java`(Java Application).

Is anyone achieve this before? If yes, Just let me how to do.

Or

Is there any other option to capture the photo from camera on Android Emulator?

Comment: These links may help u with code and guide :<br/>
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127948/timed-photo-capture-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Android emulator 2.1 my code is working to capture image**  but not working in others version of android

To start camera for capture you can start camera for capture using below intent filter

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

After capturing you will get the image as bitmap so you need to get activity result

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    if(extras.containsKey("data")) {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
        if(image != null) {
            //User this byte array in your application
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fail to capture Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Now almost in all the emulators this code is working.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Android 2.3.3 version. Is there any other option?

Comment: In emulator there is a issue only camera is working for Android-2.1 but in all device it will work fine in which there is a camera hardware so for testing purpose you can use Emulator with Android 2.1

Answer (score 2):

As hes mentioning in his article he wrote this code in haste and it may be kinda buggy therefore. It's not said to work everywhere at all.

Im assuming your using exactly this code to run this thing:

```
CameraSource cs = new SocketCamera("192.168.0.100", 9889, 320, 240, true);
if (!cs.open()) { /* deal with failure to obtain camera */ }
while(/*some condition*/) {
  cs.capture(canvas) //capture the frame onto the canvas
}
cs.close();
```

What is, by the way, the main purpose of doing such things?
All camera aligned things should tested exhaustively on a real device, because it can cause loads of problems which does not occur at an emulator. The camera implementation of the camera is for debug/testing purposes, only!

I would strongly recommend to not spend to much time into getting this running, it won't lead you very far. It still has not been tested on a real device, though, which would be the very most important.

I hope I didn't disappoint you too much with this answer :/

Comment: Even though I do agree with your answer, I must say there are certain situations where its difficult to test on a real device. In my current situation, I test on my own personal android phone at work and haven't been provided a real device and at the same time I don't have permission to connect to the work server on my personal phone. 

My application has the zxing OR code implemented - and yes I can test if this works on the device - to see if it reads it properly, but i cant send this information to the server - since i cant connect to it.