# Using emulator to test taking photos using intent

Tags: android, emulation

Can I use android emulator to test taking of photos using the intent? I am asking this because, when I use the camera in the emulator it crashes(not through any program but taking it from the emulator.) [image]

And also it may be noted that I am not able to take the picture when I click the "take photo" button in the emulator (when my program is run.)
What is happening here? Should I consider testing in a physical device instead of the emulator? Or what is the work around?

Comment: refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505647/how-to-capture-the-photo-from-camera-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

Just check it with Android avd 2.3.3(Level 10)

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

try this code

```
 protected static final int CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT = 2;

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_PICTURE_INTENT) {

            try{
                imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                img_profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                //System.out.println(cn.ConvertBase64(bmp));
                base64ImageString = mh.ConvertBase64(bmp);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual need to change the code, as per documentation, the emulator is meant to work in the exact same way as the physical device. What do you say?

Comment: May be you miss the permission.just check it once. if you give the permission it will open the camera..